# Phonegap: cannot get data from external php server

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, cordova

I've been having problems for 2 days now. Before I didn't face this, but now it gives me a lot of headaches.

I can't get the json data from external php server using jQuery get method in phonegap (newest version).

Here is my data and code:

```
Sample data: {"name":"test"}

var url = 'http://website.com/app/user.php';
   $.ajax({ 
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      data: {mb: user},
      success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      error: function () {
        alert('error');
      }
   });
```

I get the result, but not the 'test' data but totally different.
The alert is an html page rather than json data. I really don't know what is this.
I already tried the origin * and allow internet in android manifest.

I'm receiving a full valid `html` file instead of the data I expect

My guess is the problem came from the server itself?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you debug this code with `Firebug` and paste the value of the `data` in your Question? Or print out the value and paste it here?

Comment: you said you get a valid `html`. can you post the `html`? it will give us some clue as to what is the issue/error.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make requests from the localhost to a remote domain via javscript environment, the error will be "cross browser"

Recommend making an abstraction in order to pass the data for a webservice via java and not javascript.